# Proof By Induction for Equality of Two Sums and an Expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Prove the following formula for all n ≥ 1 by the principle of mathematical induction.

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{i}= 2^{n}-1$

What's confusing to me about this problem is the fact that it has two equalities rolled into one. Do I prove the two sums, 
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{i}$, equivalent to one another and *then* prove $2^{n}-1$ equivalent to one of them? Does the order matter? How do you even prove two sums equivalent (using sigma notation)?

Comment: The order in which you prove the equalities doesn't matter. However the first equality is quite trivial: Consider $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}$. We make a change of index, setting $j=i-1$. When $i=1$, we have $j=0$, and when $i=n$, we have $j=n-1$. This means that the sum goes from $j=0$ to $n-1$, and can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j$. This is precisely the second term. Of course, if you can't perform these kinds of changes of indices, you should prove it by induction as well.

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question and I think you need to ask your teacher.  My guess would be: it's easy to see by substitution that the first two expressions are the same, so just prove by induction that one of them equals the third expression.